# vmware player usb device on slackware 14.0

Tags: vmware, slackware

I just installed Slackware 14.0.  I installed vmware player using this command:

```
sh VMware-$NAME-$VERSION.bundle --console --ignore-errors
```

Which I found from this website:

> http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/installation-of-vmware-player-4-on-slackware-13-37-32-bit-909539/

That allowed me to install a guest version of Windows XP (microcontroller programming).  But I'm unable to connect a usb device to the guest xp vm.  The usb device is acting like a serial device.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is the error I'm getting when I try to connect the USB device to the guest xp vm:

serial1: Unable to open the "COM1" serial port: No such file or directory.

Comment: You can always edit your question, so I suggest you move the content of your comment into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Power down your VM and exit VMWare player. 
Locate the `.vmx` file of this virtual machine.
Open it with text editor and seek for the `serial0.fileName` parameter.

change its value to `"/dev/ttyUSB0"` (use the actual name if you have more than one USB serial device connected to you host system; they are all named with `ttyUSBxxx`, where `xxx` - is a numeric):

```
serial0.fileName = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
```

Save the file and start your VM.
It should find the port now.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this same error using a VM of Debian on Windows with VMPlayer when trying to bring in a real serial port. Everything was set properly as Serge said in his answer, it just happened that my serial port was open with another application.